# Error When Activating Unyson Plugin in Wordpress Fatal Error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-shortcode, wordpress-plugin-creation

does anyone know why when i activate unyson an error message appears like this

The plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /home/u4437453/public_html/bssys/wp-content/plugins/unyson/framework/core/components/backend.php on line 1111

I'm confused, where is the problem?
anyone can help me

Comment: There is very limited information in the question, but, as far as I can tell, there seems to be a syntax error in the plug-in code. Contact the plug-in developer to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a syntax error in the plug-in code.

I would contact the developer of the plug-in to ask for help. You can usually find information about how to report bugs and contact the developer on the plug-in's details page.